# Saving metabox keys and storing values as array

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, metabox

```
$key = "key";
$meta_boxes = array(
    "item-count" => array(
    "name" => "item-count",
    "type" => "itemcount",
    "std" => "",
    "title" => "How many items?",
    "description" => "Choose item count",
    "options" => array(
        "0" => "None", "1" => "1", "2" => "2", "2" => "2", "3" => "3", "4" => "4"),
    ),
    "item-color" => array(
    "name" => "item-color",
    "type" => "itemcolor",
    "std" => "",
    "title" => "Item Colors",
    "description" => "Choose item colors",
    "options" => array(
        "black" => "Black", "white" => "White", "red" => "Red"),
    ),
);

function create_meta_box() {
global $key;

  if ( function_exists('add_meta_box') ) {
      add_meta_box( 'item-div', 'Item Infos', 'display_meta_box', 'post', 'normal', 'high' );
  }
}
function display_meta_box() {
    global $post, $meta_boxes, $key;

    wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), $key . '_wpnonce', false, true );

    foreach($meta_boxes as $meta_box) {
    $data = get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true);

    switch ( $meta_box['type'] ) {

    case "itemcount":
    echo '<table style="margin-bottom: 20px;" class="widefat">';
    echo '<thead><tr><th>'.$meta_box['title'].'</th></tr></thead>';
    echo '<tbody style="background:#f9f9f9;"><tr><td>';
    echo'<select name="'.$meta_box['name'].'[]" multiple size="3">';
    function new_in_array( $needle, $haystack )  { if (is_array($haystack)) { return in_array($needle, $haystack); } else { return false; } }
$getcountmeta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'key', true );
$getcountmeta2 = $getcountmeta['item-count']; ?>
<?php foreach ($meta_box['options'] as $item_count_key => $item_count_option) { ?>
<option <?php if ( new_in_array($item_count_key,$getcountmeta2)) { ?> selected <?php } ?> value="<?php echo $item_count_key; ?>"><?php echo $item_count_option; ?></option>
<?php }
    echo '</select>';
    echo '<p>'.$meta_box['description'].'</p>';
    echo '</td></tr></tbody></table></div>';
    break;

    case "itemcolor":
    echo '<table style="margin-bottom: 20px;" class="widefat">';
    echo '<thead><tr><th>'.$meta_box['title'].'</th></tr></thead>';
    echo '<tbody style="background:#f9f9f9;"><tr><td>';
    echo'<select name="'.$meta_box['name'].'[]" multiple size="3">';
    function new_in_array2( $needle, $haystack )  { if (is_array($haystack)) { return in_array($needle, $haystack); } else { return false; } }
$getcolormeta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'key', true );
$getcolormeta2 = $getcolormeta['item-color']; ?>
<?php foreach ($meta_box['options'] as $item_color_key => $item_color_option) { ?>
<option <?php if ( new_in_array2($item_color_key,$getcolormeta2)) { ?> selected <?php } ?> value="<?php echo $item_color_key; ?>"><?php echo $item_color_option; ?></option>
<?php }
    echo '</select>';
    echo '<p>'.$meta_box['description'].'</p>';
    echo '</td></tr></tbody></table></div>';
    break;
    }
    }
}

function save_meta_box( $post_id ) {
global $post, $meta_boxes, $key;

foreach($meta_boxes as $meta_box) {
$data[ $meta_box[ 'name' ] ] = $_POST[ $meta_box[ 'name' ] ];

}

if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ $key . '_wpnonce' ], plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) )
return $post_id;

if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ))
return $post_id;

update_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $data );
}
```

The code i pasted above, adds the "key" meta_key to database and its meta_value is

```
a:2:{s:10:"item-count";a:2:{i:0;s:1:"1";i:1;s:1:"2";}s:10:"item-color";a:2:{i:0;s:5:"black";i:1;s:5:"white";}} //i chose counts 1 and 2, colors black and white
```

What i want to achieve is, instead of unique "key" meta_key, store those values in seperate meta keys such as

```
meta_key     item_color
meta_value   a:2:{i:0;s:5:"black";i:1;s:5:"white";}
```

I have no idea how to do this. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first line reads:

```
$key = "key";
```

And your last line reads:

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $data );
```

So, for all I can see here, if you change it to:

```
$key = "item_color";
```

You should be good to go.